# Can you mock a chain of method calls with Mocktio/PowerMock if one of them is static?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

Imagine I have the following line in a piece of code I am unit testing:

```
SomeClass.method1().method2();
```

Where SomeClass is a class, method1() is a **static method** inside SomeClass that returns some instance of, say, 'aClass', and method2() is a method that can be called from an instance of 'aClass'.

Is it possible to mock out this entire chain so that I can return a result that I want? At the moment I know I could do something similar to this:

```
BDDMockito.given(SomeClass.method1()).willReturn(mockedAClass);
when(mockedAClass.method2()).thenReturn(true);
```

But I would rather do something like this:

```
when(SomeClass.method1().method2()).thenReturn(true);
```

Is this possible?

---

EDIT: This question was marked as a duplicate, but there is one quite large difference between my question and the 'duplicate' one. In my question the first method is static, the second is not. I can't seem to get mockito to chain mock this static method, which leads me to believe it's not the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes lookup mokito returns deep stub is its lingo
http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.8.3/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write mock for a static method calls inside a non-static method.

In the below snippet, I am using the same class names as referred in the question. `method1()` is the static method defined in `SomeClass`. `method2()` is the non-static method in `AClass`.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockStatic;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.mockito.MockedStatic;

public class TestClass {    
    @Test
    void methodTest() {
        try (MockedStatic<SomeClass> someClass = mockStatic(SomeClass.class)) {
            AClass aClass = mock(AClass.class);
            someClass.when(SomeClass::method1).thenReturn(aClass);
            when(aClass.method2()).thenReturn(true);
            //...
        }
    }
}
```